# Rewrite rule for a longer url to a shorter one in htaccess (wordpress)

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Right now a complete url is like this:

**website.com/en_us/multimedia/blogs/podcast/2011/08/post-title/**

I want to shorten the above url to this one:

**website.com/podcast/2011/08/post-title/**

With a seo friendly 301 redirect.

Can anyone advice on how can i achieve this?

Thank you!

My current .htaccess file is this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# uploaded files
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?files/(.+) wp-includes/ms-files.php?file=$2 [L]

# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?wp-admin$ $1wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule  ^[_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $1 [L]
RewriteRule  ^[_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/(.*\.php)$ $1 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

To just redirect from `website.com/en_us/multimedia/blogs/podcast/2011/08/post-title/` to `website.com/podcast/2011/08/post-title/` add the following to your .htaccess file, ahead of any other rules that are there.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/en_us/multimedia/blogs/(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule . http://%{HTTP_HOST}/%1 [L,R=301]
```